# Python open file and readlines()

Tags: python, file, io

My Python code for opening the file and counts the lines in the file using `Len()` and `readlines()` is not working
This is the code I wrote

```
f = open("lorem.txt","r")
x = len(f.readlines())
f.close()
print("Number of lines", x)
```

this is the `.txt` file

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 

Nulla justo elit, sagittis et gravida at, efficitur at nunc. 

Sed leo ante, dapibus sed interdum vitae, egestas eu leo. 

Ut leo ex, interdum et vulputate sit amet, euismod in ex. 

Quisque feugiat tempus augue, at sollicitudin enim luctus quis. 

Maecenas blandit urna malesuada, scelerisque dui sit amet, malesuada sem. 

Aenean iaculis porta sem, quis pretium arcu sollicitudin nec. 

In volutpat imperdiet dolor vitae bibendum.
```

The output I got now is 0.

Comment: If you `len(list(f.readlines()))` is it still 0?

Comment: Are you sure this is the actual content and the file is not empty? this code should give you 15.

Comment: I just executed your code here and it works. Your file must be empty, or the file path is wrong.

Comment: If your program is running without error then *lorem.txt* is empty. I suggest you use an absolute path to the file whose contents you've shown. Your current working directory contains the empty file. Add this to your code *import os* then, after you've opened the file *print(os.path.realpath(f.name))*